# Enable logging in python for all users/all code on Linux

Tags: python

As an administrator of our platform, I need to log all user's python activities. Both when they run interactively and also when they submit .py programs.

I have set up an environment variable, `PYTHONSTARTUP`, that runs a .py program but it only works when I run:

```
/opt/fk/anaconda3/bin/python
```

but *not* when I run an existing Python program:

```
/opt/fk/anaconda3/bin/python filename.py
```

I thought `PYTHONSTARTUP` was some sort of an "autoexec".

Is it possible to create separate logs for all python users?

Comment: PYTHONSTARTUP only affects interactive mode.  It's not really clear what you mean by "enable logging" - are you just logging that the Python executable has been called?  All inputs and outputs?

Comment: By legal issues, we need to know what has been execuded in our environment. Because of that, I want a log file for every python session.